# Conditionally apply date filter based on column - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I have a table that looks like this:

```
| Type |  DueDate  |
|:----:|:---------:|
|   A  |  1/1/2019 |
|   B  |  2/3/2019 |
|   C  |    NULL   |
|   A  |  1/3/2019 |
|   B  |  9/1/2019 |
|   C  |    NULL   |
|   A  |  3/3/2019 |
|   B  |  4/3/2019 |
|   C  |    NULL   |
|   B  |  1/6/2019 |
|   A  | 1/19/2019 |
|   B  |  8/1/2019 |
|   C  |    NULL   |
```

What I need to accomplish is:

> Grab all rows that have Type C. For any other type, only grab them if they have a due date AFTER May 1st 2019.

This is a dummy data -- in actuality, there are 10 or 15 types and about ~125M or so rows.

I have tried `SELECT * FROM tblTest WHERE ((Type IN ('A', 'B') AND DueDate > '05-01-2019') OR Type = 'C')` but that yields exactly the table above.

Simply changing `WHERE DUEDATE >= '05/01/2019' filters out`NULL`

How can I edit my `WHERE` statement to achieve desired results of below?

```
| Type |  DueDate |
|:----:|:--------:|
|   C  |   NULL   |
|   B  | 9/1/2019 |
|   C  |   NULL   |
|   C  |   NULL   |
|   B  | 8/1/2019 |
|   C  |   NULL   |
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/049dc/4) for reference

Comment: What are you storing a date as a string?

Comment: That might just be how the `SQL FIDDLE` was set up when I copied data over from Excel. It is a `DATE` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the answer by gordon you need to use this in `or` condition.

If you have more conditions in `where clause` apart from what is mentioned in question, you need to group the conditions.

```
select *
from tbltest
where (duedate > DATE '2019-05-01' 
      or type = 'C') -- group these condition using brackets
And other_condition;
```

Actually your original query has `or` condition with all other conditions without any brackets and that yields all the rows in result.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

If your date were stored using the correct type, you would simply do:

```
select t.*
from tbltest
where duedate > date '2019-05-01' or type = 'C';
```

I would suggest you fix the `duedate` column to have the correct type.  Until that is fixed, you can workaround the problem:

```
select t.*
from tbltest
where to_date(duedate, 'MM/DD/YYYY') > date '2019-05-01' or type = 'C';
```